# Making sprites out of an arbitrary SVG file

Tags: css, svg

I have found a gorgeous, free SVG file with all 52 poker cards.

- [Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vector-cards/)
- [Image](https://cdn.rawgit.com/tyrcho/fa8bec7cc670515cd250a9dcfad5898f/raw/2d6bb400ab12bf785a29ba06202cbec789617801/Color_52_Faces_v.2.0.svg)
- [Raw content of the SVG](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tyrcho/fa8bec7cc670515cd250a9dcfad5898f/raw/2d6bb400ab12bf785a29ba06202cbec789617801/Color_52_Faces_v.2.0.svg)

I'd like to use it in a web based game to display the sprites of the cards.

Can I "split" this file into icons using css ?

I've tried following [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) but it requires to edit the SVG file to define the elements inside a def tag, which I would prefer to avoid (SVG is huge : 2MB).

I've also tried using the viewbox/viewport attributes with no success.

Note : I've also found a [cards font](http://www.cufonfonts.com/en/font/10875/playing-cards) but the quality of the rendering is so much worse ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple suggestion where `background-position` is used to move the wanted area of an image into view

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 355px;
  width: 260px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/tyrcho/fa8bec7cc670515cd250a9dcfad5898f/raw/2d6bb400ab12bf785a29ba06202cbec789617801/Color_52_Faces_v.2.0.svg);
}
.div1 {
  background-position: -490px -1155px;
}
.div2 {
  background-position: -490px -1530px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed, thanks a lot !

I made a full example with css for all 52 cards with a LESS loop here :
http://codepen.io/tyrcho/pen/rerZwv